# Perform a click on an anchor - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have many anchors with the same class name, a data attribute differentes between them.

My goal is to be able to perform a click on a specific anchor. I tried following things:

```
$('.className[data-attribute="0"]')[0].click();

$('.className[data-attribute="0"]').click();
```

**Edit:**
As suggested by comments I will try to explain more and give some HTML even if all the markup is created/loaded with javascript which makes it difficult for me to give here.

The initial content (loaded via ajax) is:

```
<div class="anchors">
     <a class="className" data-attribute="0"><img...></a>
     <a class="className" data-attribute="1"><img...></a>
     <a class="className" data-attribute="3"><img...></a>
</div>
<div class="currentImageContainer">
    <img class="my_image" ....>
</div>
```

Let's say I have a `function`  that is called when an anchor is clicked and that makes some actions on `img.my_image`.  I need this function to be called on first load, so that the first-loaded `img.my_image` receive also changes made by `function` I thought I need to trigger a click on `a[data-attribute="0"]` since image number 0 is the first loaded image.

Is there another best approach ? I hope my english conveyed correctly my message.

**Solution:**
This is case example emphasizing that calling a handler might be better than triggering its corresponding event (As mentionned by A.Wolff). All suggestions regarding triggering event was tried and failed, till I called directly handler when ajax content totally loaded. Thank you

Comment: $('.className[data-attribute="0"]').trigger('click');

Comment: What is your expected behaviour? For redirection, you need to call native DOM method as in your first posted example

Comment: @Tushar That's same behaviour as second example in OP

Comment: @A.Wolff, I don't need redirection. I have a javascript function that perfroms some styling onclick. but I need it to be exectued the first time on anchor number 0. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Tushar, thank you for your feedback, I am trying it

Comment: Provide relevant HTML markup in question. I guess you don't need to trigger any event

Comment: @A.Wolff, thank you for reading my edit.

Comment: Still mssing the 'myFuction' part, not sure what is doing but you could try: `myfunction.call($('.className[data-attribute="0"]')[0]);`  But that should be the same as `$('.className[data-attribute="0"]')[0].click();` so i'm quite sure it wouldn't work

Comment: @A.Wolff `myfunction` is doing some style changes(width, vertical-align...). But first, do you still believe I dont need to trigger any event in my situation or am I right to do so since there is an initial element whcih didnt benefit from `myfunction`. thanks

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces You'd have better to provide a jsFiddle replicating your issue with all relevant code. Triggering an event isn't 'bad', but usually it is better to call the handler instead

Comment: @A.Wolff I see what you mean, and I will do what you asked. Thank you again for your time

Comment: @A.Wolff I managed to call the handler instead of triggering event and It is working. Thank you very much.